# Changes in memcached.ini aren't being used

Tags: php, apache, session, web-applications, memcached

I'm trying to avoid memcached session lock, so I'm changing on by Ubuntu memcached.ini file located at `/usr/share/doc/php5-memcached/memcached.ini` the following line:
`memcached.sess_locking = Off`

But when I run phpinfo() I get:
[image]

I've restarted both apache2 and memcached. Why aren't my changes effecting the configuration? Can I configure this in php.ini ?

Comment: Are you sure Ubuntu is correctly reading/parsing the configuration file? Afaik ini files do not work well with Linux

Comment: How do you normally change a configuration if not through the ini file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not changing the correct .ini file, but the example located in the documentation folder.

You can find out where the correct ini file is on top in your phpinfo() next to "Additional .ini files parsed".

That's the one you should change.